# Azure AD B2C Custom Workflow UI, all works except validation always displays error

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

**Context**

I would like to integrate AD B2C authentication with my ASP .NET Core 3 web site. All works, my custom templates are applied, but custom "reset password" and "sign up" pages always display validation errors for all fields (the validation errors displayed just after the page loads)

**What I done so far**:

I striped down all code (CSS, elements and JS) from my templates, only left the mandatory `<div id="api"...>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>Hello I am in effect (unified sign up)</div>
<div id="api" data-name="SelfAsserted">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and respectively:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>Hello I am in effect (sign up)</div>
<div id="api" data-name="SelfAsserted"> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue clearly seem in the pictures. 
I am near to pull my hair, all my day went to put this POC from ground zero, then gradually strip everything, and now all seems to be in place, still unusable...

[image]

after successful navigation I got this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out if anyone interested:

My custom style must include:

```
#attributeList ul li .attrEntry .itemLevel { display: none }
```

It worth to mention that injected *sign in* div block and *sign up* div block uses inconsistent, different validation approach: for example *sign in* validates email input field on submit while *sign up* (and *reset password*) validates email input field on keystroke.

This results multiple work for you to figure out how to cooperate with the injected markup and injected javascript code.

(using v2 userflows)